# Magento. Sort products collection by position

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I have products collection.

```
$_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
```

In admin panel in Catalog->Manage Categories->Category products i have position for each product. 
**How i can sort $_products by position ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created separated extension which create new products attribute with name 'position'. In this extension i have create observer which listening category save event. So when admin save category in my observer i get each position and set my attribute 'position' for each product. And at at last i can sort products collection by 'position'(product) attribute.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to sort products by position in category $category_id. you can use the following

```
//Load the category model

 $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id)
             ->getProductCollection()
             ->addAttributeToSort('position', 'ASC');

$products_list = $category->getData();
```

you will get all products sorted by position in that category $category_id

Comment: Hello, thank you for answer. Unfortunately ->addAttributeToSort('position', 'ASC') not working in products collection

Comment: check my edited code. In that if you know the category id, you can fetch the products in that category sorted by position

Answer (score 2):

you need to add category, where you set positions for products, as filter for collection

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$collection->addCategoryFilter($category);
$collection->addAttributeToSort('position', 'ASC');
```